# Set TimeOutError's time of Soap11Request

Tags: android, soap

I am using `IceSoap` library for my soap calls in `Android` application. I am getting timeout error while calling a Service because Service is returning a very large `PDF file`. So I want to change the time for `TimeOutError`.

Can I do this? If yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a method on this site: [soapICE](http://icesoap.googlecode.com/git-history/icesoap-1.0.7/IceSoap/javadoc/com/alexgilleran/icesoap/request/impl/ApacheSOAPRequester.html) that states that you can call a method setSocketTimeout(int timeout) on the ApacheSOAPRequester. hope this helps.